# How do i format date like this 2019-07-08T10:37:28Z in flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, format, flutter-layout

I want to format the date like this `2019-07-08T10:37:28Z` but I don't know how to do it can anyone help me with this.

Here is the code for date picker

```
final format = new DateFormat.yMMMEd('en-US');

return DateTimeField(
      format: format,
      autocorrect: true,
      autovalidate: false,
      controller: _bspLicenseExpiryDate,
      readOnly: true,
      validator: (date) => date == null ? 'Please enter valid date' : null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Expiry Date",
          hintText: "Expiry Date",
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.calendar,
            size: 24,
          )),
      onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
        return showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
          initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
          lastDate: DateTime(2100),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: `DateTime` has a `.toIso8601String()` method, but it does print the fractional seconds. Try `print(DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String());`

Answer (score 13):

You can use this:

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var dateFormatted = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").format(now);
```

You have to add the "Z" at the end of the String because is a Char used to format the TimeZone.

You can check it there -> https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: You can/should quote the non-format characters - this allows you to add the Z. `var dateFormatted = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(DateTime.now());`

Comment: @Caffo17 "Z" indicates that the time represented is in UTC!

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to DateFormat class here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html
It has a constructor where you can put your pattern.

```
    final format = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ','en-US');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `UTC` type of **ISO 8601** format datetime.

Below method to parse this date format and return today default if have exception:

```
String formatDateTimeFromUtc(dynamic time){
  try {
    return new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(time));
  } catch (e){
    return new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new DateTime.now());
  }
}
```